# What is the correct way to create a case-insensitive trigram-index in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, trigram

...and is it something I should do anyway?

From my brief testing, making a trigram index and searching using

```sql
where name like '%query%'
```

is faster than

```sql
where name ilike '%query%'
```

So it seems like I should do it, but I'm surprised I've not been able to find out how.

(My test data is fairly homogenous - 1.5M rows made up of 16 entries repeated. I can imagine this might mess with the results.)

This is how I expected it to work (note the `lower(name)`):

```sql
create extension pg_trgm;

create table users(name text);

insert into users values('Barry');

create index "idx" on users using gin (lower(name) gin_trgm_ops);

select count(*) from users where (name like '%bar%');
```

but this returns `0`.

Either of

```sql
select count(*) from users where (name like '%Bar%');
```

or

```sql
select count(*) from users where (name ilike '%bar%');
```

work, which makes me believe the trigrams in the index are not `lower()`'d. Am I misunderstanding how this works under the hood? Is it not possible to call `lower` there?

I note that this

```sql
select show_trgm('Barry')
```

returns lowercase trigrams:

```
{"  b"," ba",arr,bar,rry,"ry "}
```

So I'm perplexed.

Comment: `ILIKE` can make use of the trigram index even if the data is not stored in lowercase. So all you need is `create index on users using gin (name gin_trgm_ops);` and then use `ILIKE`

Comment: I guess my naïve testing was leading me down the wrong path. 
I compared various 3-character substring-searches where I knew the values were present in the data as lowercase. ILIKE was significantly slower for each one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trigrams are definitely lower case.

The conundrum becomes cleared up when you consider how trigram indexes are used: they act as a filter that eliminates the majority of non-matches, but allow false positive results (among other reasons is their case insensitivity). That's why there always has to be a recheck to eliminate those false positives, and that us why you always get a bitmap index scan.

The `ILIKE` query may be slower because it has more results, or because case insensitive comparisons require more effort.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty obvious it would work in that way now I think through what you've said.